# SQL Server query results are interrupted with "S * Y * N * C"

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc

I am connecting to SQL Server database and making a query via Python ODBC driver. When the query result is quite big (usually 10k+ rows), the result is incomplete - the data is replaced by "S * Y * N * C" string. I tried to google the reason/solution, because of the asterisks this is not possible.

The sample query:

```
SELECT TOP 150000 * 
FROM BajonetNEW_data_test 
WHERE Zakazka = '35547597' 
ORDER BY Record ASC
```

And a part of the result:

[image: incomplete SQL result]

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

Extra information:

Python code:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password+'')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 150000 * FROM BajonetNEW_data_test WHERE Zakazka = '35547597' ORDER BY Record ASC")
data = cursor.fetchall()

print(data)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing DDL, the query, or the code that retrieves and prints the resultset, it is impossible to guess. Perhaps you have actually managed to store a string in your database that has this text (with linefeeds)? And what you posted looks like a fragment of application code, not a resultset.

Comment: Nope, string is not stored in the database and it keeps moving to different places. I edited the answer with more information, however not related to the issue itself

Comment: It is certainly possible to google `"s*y*n*c"`. This question is one of the very few results though

Comment: @MartinSmith, yes, I see now.

Comment: So I imagine the issue must be something your end as no one else ever seems to have complained about it

Comment: That might be a valid assumption, however I am not sure about that.